# How to highlight path from root to selected node in d3 js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a tree using d3 js. Now i have created a drop-down menu containing list of all the nodes in the tree. Now on selecting a node from the drop down menu,i want to highlight path from root to that particular node. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a flatten function which will make the hierarchical data into a n array.

```
function flatten(root) {
  var nodes = [],
    i = 0;

  function recurse(node) {
    if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
    if (node._children) node._children.forEach(recurse);
    if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
    nodes.push(node);
  }

  recurse(root);
  return nodes;
}
```

On the select box add a change listener like this:

```
var select = d3.select("body")
      .append("select")
      .on("change", function() {
    //get the value of the select
    var select = d3.select("select").node().value;
    //find selected data from flattened root record
    var find = flatten(root).find(function(d) {
      if (d.name == select)
        return true;
    });
    //reset all the data to have color undefined.
    flatten(root).forEach(function(d) {
      d.color = undefined;
    })
    //iterate over the selected node and set color as red.
    //till it reaches it reaches the root
    while (find.parent) {
      find.color = "red";
      find = find.parent;
    }
    update(find);//call update to reflect the color change
      });
```

Inside your update function color the path according to the data (set in the select function) like this:

```
d3.selectAll("path").style("stroke", function(d) {
          if (d.target.color) {
            return d.target.color;//if the value is set
          } else {
            return "gray"
          }
        })
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SKVV4A7a9bV0bZupS9M2?p=preview).

Comment: if a collapsed node is selected from the drop down menu...the path is highlighted internally,but that full path should also be expanded and on clicking on reset button ,the tree should reset to original.................Anyways,Thank you so very much for helping me :)

Comment: See you asked the question. I answered it. You increased the scope. I still answered it. You just cant make me do a project for you LOL... Ask complete clear question, don't go expanding the scope. If someone answers it accept it. If you have new question ask a new question in SO.

Comment: Ok cyril,Thanks a lot....i am not expanding the scope actually,that is what i initially wanted and that is quite logical....accepting your answer :) .....thanks a lot....would be really nice if you could help me further...Here's the new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370444/highlight-and-un-highlight-path-from-selected-node-to-root-node-in-a-collapsible

Comment: diagonal() is no longer supported in d4 v4 :/